# Jmeter Connection Timeout when accessing sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, jmeter, powerbi, performance-testing, connection-timeout

I'm doing some load stress test for my PowerBI service in Sharepoint.
the test case that I'm doing is simple enough :
Accessing my PowerBI report in sharepoint with 50 different users at the same time.

to do that, I'm using jmeter as my testing tools and following the tutorial that I found below:

[tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/jmeter-performance-testing.html)

This is the setting that I come up with:

a. in my Thread Group, I set 10 users to access in 10 seconds for 10 times
[image: Thread Group]

b. I also set HTTP authentication manager. I put my user(mail address) and password which I used to login into the sharepoint

c. On my HTTP request I set the Host with my sharepoint address and the path with my PowerBI report files path inside the sharepoint
[image: HTTP Request]

when I start my test plan with that setting, the result on my table showing that I have a warning
[image: Result Table]

and when I check the log, it shows that my connection into sharepoint has been timed out
[image: log]

Do anyone knows where did I set wrong?
or maybe a tutorial to set the Jmeter itself would be appreciated.

regards,

add my HTTP authentication info.
BASE URL : inserted microsoft ID login page and my company login page
Username : my company AD email
Password : my company AD password
[image: authentication]

Comment: Would you please show how your authentication manager looks like?

Comment: @YuriG added my HTTP authentication info on my post

Comment: Just in case: make sure BASIC auth is on & configured on SharePoint site. Then, I would try to sniff what's going on in communication between two sites in JMeter case AND when you approach it from browser. Observed difference may give you a clue on what's the culprit. Use Fiddler for that, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint application test in JMeter, It's better to use the Recording template or configure test plan to record steps.
Otherwise, for authentication error will show every time. I have used test recording for SharePoint applications